# combine/group xml element attributes in one line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would like to know how to combine/group elements in one line  named "DATA" in SQL to XML. It is similar, but not identical to: [combine/group xml element attributes in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766999/combine-group-xml-element-attributes-in-one-line)

I have created an example Table and my try in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8819e/1 using MS Sequal Server 2017

To make my problem more clear,  below is the SQL code, current output and desired output.

## SQL Example data

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
  date datetime,
  name varchar(50)
  );
  
 INSERT INTO testTable (date, name)
 VALUES ('1901-01-01 00:00:00', 'a'), ('1902-02-02 00:00:00', 'b')
```

## SQL Query

```
select * from testTable FOR XML path('EventList'), ROOT ('Events')
```

## Current output

```
<Events>
  <EventList>
    <date>1901-01-01 00:00:00</date>
    <name>a</name>
  </EventList>
  <EventList>
    <date>1902-02-02 00:00:00</date>
    <name>b</name>
  </EventList>
  <EventList>
<Events>
```

## Desired output

```
<Events>
  <EventList>
    <DATA date="1901-01-01 00:00:00" name="a" />
    <DATA date="1902-02-02 00:00:00" name="b" />
  </EventList>
</Events>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `FOR XML AUTO` then [the table name becomes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-auto-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-ver16) the name of each row node.

The outer node can be specified using `ROOT` but you can only do one level so you need to nest it

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT *
    FROM testTable DATA
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('Events'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('EventList'), TYPE;
```

Alternatively [you can do `FOR XML PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/columns-with-a-name?view=sql-server-ver16) for the subquery also

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT
      date AS [@date],
      name AS [@name]
    FROM testTable
    FOR XML PATH('DATA'), ROOT('Events'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('EventList'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fb1964efed59ac0233de3b2e9ede17b)